# modx send and get via url (get request) variable

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution, get-request

I need to form a link with some parameters in it like this:

```
<a href="[[~[[*id]]? &sorting=`Data.price`]]">
```

and then I want to get the parameters in my getPage snippet like this:

```
[[!getPage:default=`Ничего не найдено`?
    &element=`msProducts`
    &parents=`[[*id]]`
    &sortby=`[[*sorting]]`
    &sortdir=`ASC`
]]
```

How to accomplish this task properly? How to send and then get user's parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setPlaceholders extra  - https://github.com/oo12/setPlaceholders

```
[[!setPlaceholders? &ph=`sorting == get.sorting`]]
```

and then use [[+sorting]] it in your getPage construction

```
[[!getPage:default=`Ничего не найдено`?
    &element=`msProducts`
    &parents=`[[*id]]`
    &sortby=`[[+sorting]]`
    &sortdir=`ASC`
]]
```

Comment: but how attach also id? i need id and sorting to put in url

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop through the _get variables in a snippet and set them all yourself, that way you don't have to specify which placeholder you are looking for with an extra snippet call each time and it gives you the opportunity to either sanitize your variables or do any extra processing.

```
$placeholderArray = array();

foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) { 

    $placeholderArray[$key] = $value;

}

$modx->setPlaceholders(array($placeholderArray));

return;
```

**UPDATE**

First, your link is wrong:

```
<a href="[[~[[*id]]? &sorting=`Data.price`]]">
```

should look like:

```
<a href="[[~[[*id]]]]?sorting=Data.price">
```

if you want to add more parameters or 'data.price' is a modx placeholder:

```
<a href="[[~[[*id]]]]?sorting=[[+Data.price]]&value2=[[+data.number]]">
```

I strongly suggest you read the modx developer documentation, all this is covered there: http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx

Comment: how to call, how to get this id and sorting val

Comment: just stick that code in a snippet at the top of your template, any get variables passed to the page will be available as a placeholder of the same name. The [[*id]] is the current page id and will be available anywhere is the template with or without the script

Comment: please give wright code: for example in link href="[[*id]]" and how to attach second param? and how to get it? i didn't understand right syntax

Comment: hm, maybe you mean for two params: <a href="[[~[[*id]]]]&sorting=Data.price">

Comment: hm doc is good, but i need this only once ) i just want to know how to do it, without wasting many time, thank you. see i set this in link   <a href="[[~[[*id]]]]&sorting=Data.price">   and how do i get sorting value in other view? like <h6>[[get_url_params[*sorting]]</h6> something like this) please help me with this, i know that i'm very lazy, but i need only one this, i'm not a modx developer at all (

Comment: i see how it is done here http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/basic-development/snippets   but how to do in my task? :///